# Pivot table error with Office version 2016

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

My Office version is 365 2019. When running the same code in an Office 2016, it brings me quarters and not months, so I have an error. I think it may be for the quarters.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotCache
     ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").NullString = "0"
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Codigo SIC")
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Fecha")
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Fecha").AutoGroup

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Quarters").PivotItems( _
    "Qtr1").ShowDetail = True

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Years").PivotItems("2019") _
    .ShowDetail = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Fecha").Orientation = _
    xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Quarters").Orientation = _
    xlHidden
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Fecha")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 2
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Years").ShowDetail = True

Range("F4").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").RowGrand = False
Range("E4").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Years").Subtotals = Array( _
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
Range("F10").Select

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "ResumenRuido").PivotFields("Penalidad"), "Sum of Penalidad", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
ActiveSheet.Name = "Resumen_penalidades"

Range("E10").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido").NullString = ""

Call tabla_resumen_energia

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest to use a reference to your pivottable to shorten the code. After these two lines you can replace every "ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido")" by "pt".

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ResumenRuido")
```

Instead of `PivotField.AutoGroup` I suggest to use a dedicated ungroup/group method to ensure you get the wanted periods, e. g. years and quarters and months:

```
With pt.PivotFields("Fecha")
    ' if already grouped, first ungroup it:
    If .TotalLevels > 1 Then .DataRange.Cells(1).Ungroup

    ' sort it:
    .AutoSort Order:=xlAscending, Field:="Fecha"

    ' group it by wanted periods:
    ' seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, quarters, years
    .DataRange.Cells(1).Group _
        Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, True, True)
End With
```

#### Bug with grouping a PivotField

I can confirm, there is a bug (at least in my Excel version "Office 365 Pro Plus, Version 1902, Build 11328.20100 click and run"). If I manually select a grouping for a pivot field with dates, the lowest selected period is always **not shown** as additional PivotField.
Example: If I group years/quarters/months by hand or with my a. m. code, the months are not shown!

---

#### Workaround

Group with an additional lower period (which in some Excel versions is not shown) and later hide it also, if it is shown:

```
    .DataRange.Cells(1).Group _
        Periods:=Array(False, False, False, True, True, True, True)

' ...

Dim pf As PivotField
For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    Select Case pf.Name
    Case "Fecha", "Quarters", "Months", "Days"
        pf.Orientation = xlHidden
    End Select
Next pf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Fine :) Please mark my answer as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).